# How to make part of the scroll, horizontal in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, anime.js

I want to make part of the normal scroll, horizontal without any scrollbars or left/right handles. (shown below)

[image]

Also, I don't want to use jquery or framer motion. As shown in the gif, the horizontal scroll is part of the normal scrollbar, it's like they are all part of one scroll view.

Comment: what is it that you tried? show us your code and we will see whats wrong with it

Comment: There is no code, just imagine a list of divs. I'm looking for a hint of how to achieve such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to get it this far, i believe it should need more tweaking?
hope this helps.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-snrwjp?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).